# Concatenating Two strings in Localization Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring, stringwithformat

My Previous Code without Localization. It worked perfect.

```
case LOGIN_LOGOUT: ((Cell*)cell).lbl.text = [self isLoggedIn] ?   
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Logout %@", email]   
:NSLocalizedString(@"Login", @"Message");
 break;
```

But when I implement Localization in **Logout** the email will not show.

```
case LOGIN_LOGOUT: ((Cell*)cell).lbl.text = [self isLoggedIn] ?   
[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Logout", @"Message") ,"%@",   
email] :NSLocalizedString(@"Login", @"Message");
break;
```

I know I am missing some basics in `stringWithFormat` but can anyone offer some guidance to me?

Comment: I think you are better off localising the complete phrase as there could be a different word order in some languages (or other, more complicated issues).

Comment: Everything is good (if that's the whole phrase, not part of bigger phrase), just add object format specifier (%@) to your .strings entry.

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii  like below answer??

Answer (score 1):

You are looking up the localisation of "Logout". You are using that as a format string. That's not likely to work. Don't make statements that are too complex, it makes it impossible to debug.

I'd write

```
case LOGIN_LOGOUT: {
    NSString* labelText; 
    if ([self isLoggedIn]) {
        NSString* formatString = NSLocalizedString(@"Logout", @"Message");
        labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString, "%@", email];
    } else {
        labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Login", @"Message");
    }

    ((Cell*)cell).lbl.text = labelText;
    break;
}
```

And now you can actually debug that whole mess. The stringWithFormat parameters look very, very dodgy.

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii: Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume, that you have .strings file and it contains entry named **"Logout"**. You have:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Logout", @"Message") ,"%@", email]
```

here you try to load format string via `NSLocalizedString` and use it with `NSString`. That means that you have to put correct format string into your .strings file, so, if currently you have:

```
"Logout" = "Logout";
```

In order to make it just like before localization, you need:

```
"Logout" = "Logout %@";
```

If you don't have a .strings file or don't have entry named **"Logout"**, `NSLocalizedString` will return the key, i.e.

```
NSLocalizedString(@"key", @"comment") // returns "key"
```

That means, that your `NSLocalizedString(@"Logout", @"Message")` may return **"Logout"** if `NSLocalizedString` can't find correct entry in your .strings file.

There are more things that may go wrong, if you want some deeper insides on that, I have written great article on the whole topic: [Understanding iOS internationalization](http://maniak-dobrii.com/understanding-ios-internationalization/).

Also I'd suggest to use `+localizedStringWithFormat:` instead of just plain `+stringWithFormat:`, because the former uses current locale.

Comment: dude it's not working my app crash. -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL

Comment: Something is really messed up, I can't even guess what caused that error. The only way we can figure it out is if you provide your code in your question.

Comment: And don't just copy paste the code, your problem is deeper than you think. You can't deal internationalization like that, it will bite you bad if you do.

Comment: which types of problems will occur in future? Please tell me

Comment: @iosDev There are a lot of stuff to deal with, check the link I provided.